# How to make a function use only predefined constants in its constructor parameters in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I've been looking around trying to figure this out. But even reading the source code of some libraries didn't give me a good understanding of how to do this:

I have a function in Kotlin :

```
fun setCustomMode(customMode: Int) {
}
```

And I have a few Int constants: CUSTOM_MODE_1, CUSTOM_MODE_2

How can I allow the function `setCustomMode` to only accept the constants above. I searched a lot but I can't even seem to know how to ask the question properly on Google. Please help me.

Comment: How about an `enum class`?

Comment: @Sweeper I tried implementing an enum class but I don't know exactly how to use it with a constructor. Can you please explain ?

Comment: Please show your attempt, and ask that question instead. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @Sweeper I could do no attempt. I mentioned in my post that I couldn't even figure out a proper way to ask the question, and looking up "Using enum classes with functions" returned nothing useful. Thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achive this by declaring [enum](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/enum-classes.html) class. Sample is below:

```
enum class Modes(val id: Int) {
    CUSTOM_MODE_1(123), //Desired int
    CUSTOM_MODE_2(456) //Another desired int
    //...
}

fun setCustomMode(modes: Modes) {
    println("Name of the mode is " + modes.name)
    println("ID of the mode is " + modes.id)
}

fun main() {
    setCustomMode(Modes.CUSTOM_MODE_1) //Anything from Modes class
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted ! It's weird how I got nothing from searching up Google. Thank you very much.